# Semitransparent form that skips (or sends to background) mouse input?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.0

How can I make a form that whatever I do with the mouse on it, it will be like the form is not there and whatever is behind (that is going to be part of my app to) will receive all mouse input. What I want to make is basically a tutorial that highlights controls that the user needs to click. I know how to generate clicks but I would like to extend the functionality to every possible mouse input. I tried handling `WndProc` in my form and send the message to whatever is behind but that was a mess. Is there any better way to do this?

Another possibility is to keep my form transparent and paint around whatever control should receive mouse input but I just want to know if the highlight thing (painting over the control with a semitransparent brush) is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a tutorial window (semi transparent) with the constructor taking a parameter of the parent window.
In the MouseDown / MouseUp events of the window call the mouse down / mouse up event handler of the parent.

public partial class ParentWindow : Window
{
    public ParentWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

```
private void testButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TutorialWindow tutorialWindow = new TutorialWindow(this);
    tutorialWindow.Show();
}

public void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

}

And the TutorialWindow class

public partial class TutorialWindow : Window
{
    private ParentWindow parent;

```
public TutorialWindow(ParentWindow parent)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.parent = parent;
}

private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.parent.Window_MouseDown(sender, e);
}
```

}

The properties of the Tutorial window can be modified to make it semi-transparent and even 'fade' away when the user click in the window.